# $('#id').value is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble with trying to check the length of a field and set a value based on the result. Using firebug with firefox I keep getting the error 'elUsername' is not defined. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Fairly new to JQuery.

```
$('#usernameInput').blur(function ()
{
    var elUsername = $('#usernameInput').value;
    var elUsernameFeedback = $('#usernameFeedback');
    if (elUsername.length < 5) {
        elUsernameFeedback.text("Please enter your username");
    }
});
```

Basically when the user leaves the field and the username is less than 5 (just for testing) the  gets the text set to it to prompt the user to correct the mistake. However the if statement is never entered. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error message doesn't lie. Note how much more relevant the updated title is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to use a native JavaScript property on a jQuery object. Use :

```
var elUsername = $('#usernameInput').val();
```

or

```
var elUsername = document.getElementById('usernameInput').value;
```

or the slightly less obvious, but still valid:

```
var elUsername = $('#usernameInput')[0].value;
var elUsername = $('#usernameInput').get(0).value;
```

Comment: Am I correct in saying that [0].value / get.(0).value will pull the first element that the JQuery search finds? Cheers.

Comment: Each jQuery object masquerades as an array, so using get(0) and [0] both result in the underlying DOM node. See http://api.jquery.com/get/ for more.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var elUsername = $('#usernameInput').val();
```

Instead of

```
var elUsername = $('#usernameInput').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change those variables to this:

```
var elUsername = $('#usernameInput').val();
```